# Rails: Redirect in routes when input is domain.com/?r=123

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I am using Rails (3.0.3) and is redirecting an entire php-page. I am doing this in my routes and it works fine, for example:

```
match '/raknare/klart.php' => redirect("/raknare"), :status => 301
```

Now, I want to fetch a counter that has this value

**/raknare/?r=123** (where 123 is an ID that doesn't matter. In php it is actuall index.php?r=123) and redirect it to /this-other-folder.

I want, however, that /raknare/ should NOT be redirected. So, it is conditional if it has that get query in it.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in my controller instead (much easier) with a:

```
    unless params[:r].blank?
        redirect_to(thisnewfil_url) and return
    end
```